# Npm scripts - how to minify files from a folder and save them into another?

Tags: npm, terser

I'm using npm scripts to compile and minify sass and potentionally javascript files.
However, I'm looking for at way to specify a source folder of `*.js` files and have them minified and saved in a destination folder individually - (flattened, not concatenated) each as `*.min.js`.

I have tried with npm terser, but it doesn't seem to be able to with with a source folder, only single files, nor does it seem to be able to minify the files individually.

So, what I'm looking for:

```
Src/
 |__main.js
 |__menu.js
 |__etc...
Dist/
 |__main.min.js
 |__menu.min.js
 |__...
```

Which npm package should I use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that the package [Terser folder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser-folder) can do just this...